# Pandas Dynamic Groupby and then using something like to_html() with Flask

Tags: python, flask, dynamic, pandas-groupby, jinja2

I am trying to display a grouped object into html with the to_hmtl(), however I am having trouble wrapping the object through render_template() and then displaying all the group dataframes with flask on my html page.

Python:

```
groups = pandas_table.groupby(pandas_table.City)
#pandas_table is my dataframe and City is a column
#also in my code pandas_table will be variable in size potentially containing a lot of
#different cities
```

So, imagine the groups object now has 3 separate dataframes with 3 keys being the city names (ex. Boston, New York, Los Angeles) with other columns like population and gdp or something else. I know to display this is in the terminal I'd do:

```
for city, city_df in groups:
    print(city, city_df)
```

And it would print the key (i.e. Boston, New York, etc.) and then each key's dataframe with city_name, city_population, city_gdp, etc. as columns in the dataframes. But, how can I pass this group through flask's render_template() and then write html and jinja to display each key's dataframe in the group.

Because something pseudo like:

```
{% for city, city_df in groups%}
<h2>{{city}}</h2>
{{city_df}}
{% endfor %}
```

Does not work. I want to use to_html(), but I do not think you can with grouped objects. My project involves a dynamic pandas dataframe dependent on the user, so the group size is variable and revolves around say...a user inputting a series of cities, and then scraping the web to get data on each city.

So what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Jinja probably generates the templates beforehand so my solution should be avoided if you're dealing with huge data which might cause memory problems. Also be careful using the `safe` filter. All in all it's definitely doable and it can be tweaked depending on what you are trying to achieve.

```py
# app.py

import pandas
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=".")

@app.route("/")
def main():
    d = {"col1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], "col2": [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]}
    df = pandas.DataFrame(d)
    ggs = df.groupby(df.col2)

    ggs = (gg.to_html() for _, gg in ggs)
    return render_template("example.html", ggs=ggs)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5001, debug=True)
```

```
<!-- example.html -->

{% for gg in ggs %}
{{ gg|safe }}
{% endfor %}
```

[image: table_img]

Comment: Ya so far I have been trying to avoid safe filters and such as it can be buggy. Just been storing tuples and table headers, but I cannot do that for this problem. Why is it that keywords like `safe` are not ideal? How have other languages like Javascript mastered these types of issues in terms of memory and compatibility? This was helpful btw, as I had something like this, but it wasn't exactly what I needed.

Comment: @BrendanLydon it's not a big deal. Since you are using `to_html` method it's just fine to pass it to `safe` in this case. I am not sure what you really need though. `to_html` can't be called from the template.